# wrap C ++ function in c # that returns pointer

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I have the following C ++ function and I would make the wrapper function in c #:

```
byte* FunctionReturnVectorPoint()
{
   return vectorPoint;
}
```

I tried so:

```
[DllImport("DLL_NAME.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
unsafe public static extern byte*[] FunctionReturnVectorPoint();
```

but it does not work.

You have any suggestions?

Comment: You should explain why it doesn't work

Comment: Your calling convention is incorrect. Read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: I changed to this: [DllImport("DLL_NAME.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr FunzioneC();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

```
[DllImport("DLL_NAME.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public static extern IntPtr FunctionReturnVectorPoint();
```

and calling the function in this way:

```
IntPtr tempPoint = FunctionReturnVectorPoint();
byte[] vector= new byte[dimensionVector];
Marshal.Copy(tempPoint , vector, 0, dimensionVector);
```